# css ul list multiple item alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ul element that conatins multiple items in line. I put my list in 300px fixed panel.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:300px">
<div class="panel-heading"> Menu Items</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" ></span>
                </button>
               A Long Menu Item Name 
                <div class="settings">
                    <div class="show-settings pull-rigth">
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>
                            </button>              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>           
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my css settings is here

```
 ul, li { 
    list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}

ul { padding-left: 1em; }
li { padding-left: 0; }

.show-settings{ 
    display: none;
}
.settings:hover .show-settings{
    display : block;
}

.content{
    position: relative;    
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 0.2em;
    *padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    background: #D9EDF7 ;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;  
}
```

[Working code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/hgjuLv6g/7/).

My settings class item is going out of blue content.

[image]

My settings button count may be 3 or 4. Is it possible to overflow to the menu item the text like this:

[image]

Or flowing new line in content.

Comment: And please also correct the type error as its right.. show-settings pull-rigth here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your structure a bit. try the below code, you can even fine tune it.

**Html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:300px">
    <div class="panel-heading"> Menu Items</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="content">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" ></span>
                    </button>
                    <span class="title">A Long Menu Item Name A Long Menu Item Name</span>
                    <div class="settings">
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="show-settings pull-rigth">
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>
                            </button>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 ul, li { 
    list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}

ul { padding-left: 1em; }
li { padding-left: 0; }

.show-settings{ 
    display: none;
}
.settings{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 9px;
    width: 75px;
}
.settings:hover .show-settings{
    display : block;
}

.content{
    position: relative;    
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 0.2em;
    *padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    background: #D9EDF7 ;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    position: relative;
}
span.title {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.btn-default{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline` to your `settings` class

```
.settings{
    display:inline;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hgjuLv6g/4/)**

---

**UPDATE**

You have a **typo** in writing a class below `div.settings`. It is as below:

```
<div class="show-settings pull-rigth">
                           <!--^^^^^-->
```

It should have been

```
<div class="show-settings pull-right">
```

May be its in fiddle but still a point to note.

Comment: I change my menu ıtem name as "A Long Menu Item Name" but now settins buttons are going down. I will update code now.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Rao actually, `float` or `display:inline-block` are better so he can use `margin` and more

Comment: So how you want it when name is so long? @bookmarker. hide the extra name or make this controls above that?

Comment: @bookmarker You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

**in css -**

`.settings { display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; }`

`.menu-label { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }`

**in html -**

change this

`</button>
                    A Long Menu Item Name
                    <div class="settings">`

to this

`</button>
                    <span class="menu-label">A Long Menu Item Name</span>
                    <div class="settings">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:right; margin-top:3px;` to the `.settings` class.